# GTX 1070 8gbs Rendering In Cycles Out Of Memory

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I don't quit understand why my blender is running out of memory. Is this memory for the GPU or The CPU.

GPU:GTX 1070 Armor 8gbs

CPU:i7-6700 4.00ghz

Ram:16gbs

Scene Info, Verts:1,601,803 Faces:1,422,392 Tris:2,844,680 Image Size 1920X1080
1200 samples
I am trying to make a house with trees and grass around it. I am not using volume scattering, I used subsurf on quite a few objects in the scene and I have no clue about bit size or depth.

Picture of Scene.
[image]

One screen the only card in the system and I am using windows 10

Comment: If you are rendering on GPU, you'll only have 8 gigabytes of memory to work with, but you should post a screenshot of your blender screen to check the memory usage.

Comment: This question gets asked quite often and in most cases it comes down to a scene that is way more complex that what the card can handle. So please [edit] your question and describe what you want to render. How many Vertices/Faces/Tris are you dealing with? (you can see those numbers on the top bar on the blender window)  Are you using particles? Are you using subsurf modifiers? If so, how many levels of subdivisions? What is the size and bit depth of the textures used? Are you using volume scatter? How many samples are you using? What is the size of the image you are rendering?

Comment: Is the card the only GPU in the system? How many monitors are connected to it and what resolution screen are they. Are you running any other apps that use resources from the GPU? As you see, there are a large number of factors that might be causing this issue. We know nothing about your scene, so give us more information to help you better.

Comment: @cegaton is that most of the info you need?

Comment: maybe this link will help you: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing

Comment: @cegaton I know this isn't chat but when I make the render layer and hit render will it render all three. For example I have HOUSE TREES/GRASS TOWEL/ROCK. when I hit render it renders all three in there own areas or just renders HOUSE but excludes the other 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have an ambitious project that goes beyond what the hardware can do... well you will run out of resources. Even 8 gigs of vRAM is not a lot (some of the resources are also not available since the card is also being used for the images on the monitor or monitors)

Every element in your scene uses some memory. Once you add it all up, the demand for resources can easily push beyond what your GPU can handle.

Multiple Particles systems for grass, leaves and such will eat up a lot of vRAM in no time. Large textures and multiple subsurf modifiers among many other things can also use a lot of resources.

You have many non exclusive options:

- Simplify your scene (reduce the number of vertices, particles and subdivisions, use smaller textures, bake complex shaders into simpler materials, etc). Can you get rid on unseen elements? How much detail do you really need in the final rendered scene?
- Split the scene in different components that are manageable by your system and composite them later into a single image.
- Render on CPU, probably slower, but you are not limited by the amount of memory on the GPU anymore, and even if you run out of RAM the system can probably use some form of Disk Cache...

Part of the art of 3D is dealing with the reality of your computing power. Time- Low cost-Quality... choose any two at the expense of the third one.

In an ideal world we want to render using all of the best settings with unlimited detail... but for all of us with a limited budget and limited lifetimes, we have to learn to optimize.